# How do I change the name of a Grails domain class id field?

Tags: grails, orm, grails-orm, hibernate-mapping, grails-domain-class

I have a Grails 2.2.3 domain class called `FundType` that I am trying to map to a legacy database table. It has two fields: `code` and `description`. I would like the `id` to be called `code` anytime I use the domain class and preferably on any of the generated scaffolding. But every time I use the name key on `id` I get this exception:

```
| Error 2013-07-24 09:38:44,855 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [com.company.scholallow.FundType]:  null
Message: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [com.company.scholallow.FundType]:  null
```

This is what my domain class consists of:

```
class FundType {

    String id
    String description

    static mapping = {
        id column: 'fund_code', generator: 'assigned', name: 'code'
        description column: 'fund_desc'
    }
}
```

And anytime I am using a FundType instance I would like to call code like `fundTypeInstance.code` and NOT `fundTypeInstance.id`. This will make it more user friendly for me because I'm dealing with something called code, not id.

So I would like to know is what I'd like to do possible? And what am I doing wrong in my domain class that is causing this ORM mappings error?

**Edit:**

Okay, so I changed my domain class to the following and I am getting a FundType not found with ID null error.

```
class FundType {

    String code
    String description

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'code'
        code column: 'fund_code'
        description column: 'fund_desc'
    }
}
```

I added some sql logging to see what Hibernate is doing and this is what was output: `select * from ( select this_.FUND_CODE as RTVFTYP1_1_0_, this_.FUND_DESC as RTVFTYP2_1_0_ from RTVFTYP this_ ) where rownum <= ?`

Comment: @JamesKleeh Yes, it is!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `String code` instead of `String id` in the domain class.

You are deliberately mentioning to the GORM that I want to use the property `code` which maps to table column `fund_code` whose value is assigned as the `id` (primary key). In that case, you just need to have the property `code`defined in the domain class instead of the `id`.

Comment: I wondered that. So I changed it and upon doing that I get the following error:

    URI
    /scholarship-allowance/fundType/list
    Class
    java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException
    Message
    ORA-00904: "THIS_"."CODE": invalid identifier

It looks like GORM things that there should be a code column in the FundType table. So I added `static transients = ['code']` and that didn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the response @doelleri. Adding that results in `FundType not found with id null` when I try to access the URI $root/fundType/list.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm answering the fix that worked for me for future use by other programmers)

@dmahapatro was right, I needed to add `String code`.

It looks like naming the id something different just doesn't play well with Grails dynamic scaffolding. I did some tests and I can still use `FundType.get(code)` and it will return the object just as if I passed in an id. I can also do `FundType.findByCode(code)`.

It looks like I have to change the scaffolded controller to expect a String id instead of the default Long id. I also have to change the scaffolded list view to send `fundTypeInstance.code` instead of `fundTypeInstance.id` to the show controller, but I suspect that adding a getId() that just returns this.code will fix that.